# Boolean condition in vecorized operation Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization, boolean-expression

I have the following summation [image]

where: s,k,q,l are integers {-n...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...,n}. 'P' and 'V' are stored as a (2n+1)*(2n+1) matrix, 'q' and 'f' are (2n+1)*1 array. How do I vecorize this operation? For loops separating the possible cases are ok for |n|<=10 but my objective is to do this in |n|>100 where it is taking too much time.

So far my idea is to find all corresponding indices for the valid combinations (s,k,q) and then operate all the products at once

```
preSum=q(valid_permutation).*f(valid_permutation).*P(valid_permutation).*V(valid_permutation);
```

and then sum all the elements to obtain the final result.

Comment: Your idea seems correct to me. I'd create **column** vectors for `s`, `k` and `q`, such that `s(i)+k(i)+q(i)==0`, then do `sum(sum(q.*f(s).*P(k,:).*V(q,end:-1:1)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it by myself after a while.

This is my solution:
(initial variables)

```
n=50; kn=-n:n; Qq=kn;
Vql=rand(2*n+1); Pkl=rand(2*n+1); Fs=rand(2*n+1,1);
```

Now I create a couple of dummy variables:

```
pk=repmat(kn,(2*n+1),(2*n+1)^2);
pk=pk(:);

vk=repmat(kn,(2*n+1)^2,(2*n+1));
vk=vk(:);

fk=repmat(kn,(2*n+1)^3,1);
fk=fk(:);

Perms=[fk vk pk]; % Possible combinations of all 3 indices of the sum
Inds=find(sum(Perms,2)==0); % valid combinations that satisfy s+k+q==0
```

Now I do transform my matrix Vql, Pkl, Fs and Qq so they correspond to have the same layout as my dummy variables:

```
Vk_ord=flipud(Vql);
repmat(Vk_ord,(2*n+1),(2*n+1));
Vk_ord=Vk_ord(:);

Q_ord=repmat(Qq,(2*n+1)^2,2*n+1);
Q_ord=Q_ord(:);

Pk_ord=repmat(Pkl(:),(2*n+1)^2,1);

F_ord=repmat(Fs,(2*n+1)^3,1);
F_ord=Fkreord(:);
```

Finally, I concat all my rearranged vectors and take only the ones with a valid indices combination, compute the products and then the resulting summation:

```
preSum=[F_ord(Inds) Vk_ord(Inds) Q_ord(Inds) Pk_ord(Inds)];

preSum=prod(preSum,2);

Summation=sum(preSumation);
```